# Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en EntityFramework.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un proyecto en asp.net MVC 5 Y cree un controlador en base a un modelo que ya tenia creado al momento de entrar al Action index de este controlador me lanza una excepcion de tipo System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, si alguien sabe la solucion me seria de mucha ayuda, a continuacion dejare partes de mi codigo:

Mi controlador:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using HelloWorld.Models;

namespace HelloWorld.Controllers
{
    public class PeliculasController : Controller
    {
        private HelloWorldContext db = new HelloWorldContext();

        // GET: Peliculas
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Peliculas.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Peliculas/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Pelicula pelicula = db.Peliculas.Find(id);
            if (pelicula == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(pelicula);
        }

        // GET: Peliculas/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Peliculas/Create
        // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
        // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Titulo,EstaEnCartelera,Genero")] Pelicula pelicula)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Peliculas.Add(pelicula);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(pelicula);
        }

        // GET: Peliculas/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Pelicula pelicula = db.Peliculas.Find(id);
            if (pelicula == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(pelicula);
        }

        // POST: Peliculas/Edit/5
        // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
        // más información vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Titulo,EstaEnCartelera,Genero")] Pelicula pelicula)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(pelicula).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(pelicula);
        }

        // GET: Peliculas/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Pelicula pelicula = db.Peliculas.Find(id);
            if (pelicula == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(pelicula);
        }

        // POST: Peliculas/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Pelicula pelicula = db.Peliculas.Find(id);
            db.Peliculas.Remove(pelicula);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Mi HelloWorldContext:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class HelloWorldContext : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        public HelloWorldContext() : base("name=HelloWorldContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<HelloWorld.Models.Pelicula> Peliculas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Mi connectionstrings:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HelloWorld-20190326120105.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HelloWorld-20190326120105;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HelloWorldContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=HelloWorldContext-20190327224332; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HelloWorldContext-20190327224332.mdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

El error que lanza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se produjo una excepción de tipo `'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en EntityFramework.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario`

> Información adicional: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a
>   Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is
>   properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is
>   enabled.)

Comment: como puedes mas que capturar la excepcion primero debes establecer la coneccion de tu BD

Comment: y modifica tu etiqueta porque tu aplicacion  es mvc-5 o .net core no puede ser ambas

Answer (score 0):

Tienes declarados en tu WebConf 2 strings de conección los cuales acceden a la misma BD

deberías quedarte con el primero y cambiar el name `DefaultConnection` por el base(name) de tu Contexto, en este caso

HelloWorldContext

```
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="HelloWorldContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HelloWorld-20190326120105.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HelloWorld-20190326120105;Integrated Security=True"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />        
      </connectionStrings>
```

Despues de Guardar los cambios, en la Consola de Adminsitrador de Paquetes de VS pasa los comandos:

```
Enable-Migrations //activa las migraciones en tu proyecto
Add-Migration primera //crea un archivo de migración de BD con elnombre primera, en caso de que existan cambios en tu modelo, lo verás en el archivo
Update-Database //actualiza tu BD con los cambios de la migración
```

Answer (score -2):

Pienso que quizás modificaste algo en el esquema de la base de datos, y olvidaste actualizar el Entity Data Model. Intenta actualizar el modelo de la base de datos.

Revisa que el detalle de la asignación sea la correcta, ya que si cambiaste un tipo de dato este error persistirá.

También podrías mencionar la vista que falló (listar, insertar etc).

Comment: podrias ampliar tu respuesta y agregar elementos en la configuracion correcta,la respuesta es muy vaga.